# nginx: override global ssl directives for specific servers

Tags: nginx, ssl

In my configuration I have placed the ssl_* directives inside the http block and have been using a wildcard certificate certified by a custom CA without any problems. However, I now want to use a new certificate for a new subdomain (a server), that has been certified by a recognized CA.

Let's say the TLD is blah.org. I want my custom certificate with CN *.blah.org to be used on all domains except for new.blah.org that will use its own certificate/key pair of files with CN new.blah.org.

How would one do that? Adding new ssl_* directives inside the server block doesn't seem to override the global settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, settings in `server` stanzas *do* override those set in the surrounding `http` stanza, although I must admit I've never tried to set SSL parameters (given that you usually only have SSL config in your SSL vhosts).

You might want to describe exactly *why* you think it isn't working, and provide debug logs and your config files so the cause of your dilemma can be identified.

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that the default ssl certificate in the http block is a wildcard one. Unfortunately, I've been googling with no results and there's no errors in the logs.

Comment: No, nginx doesn't care what's in your certificates.  I'm not asking for logs to look for errors, I'm interested in the debug information.

Comment: For some strange reason nginx restart script failed to restart the process yet it did report as though nginx was successfully restarted. After a bit of looking through logs, I realized that and manually did a restart and it worked sucessfully. So nginx ssl_* directives are overriding as expected.